# Sharepoint 2010 + swf + interaction

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, flash

I am very new to actionscript 3.

I have created 5 buttons at the end of my flash animation, which i am going to add in a sharepoint site. I need to open a sharepoint list/forms (not in a new page) by clicking the 5 buttons, the sharepoint guys gave me links to those forms but said i need to pass the links to the site through javascript code. I am not sure what to do, as i am a designer and not a programmer, i have no clue what to do. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is this:

```
/Lists/<LISTNAME>/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2F<LISTNAME>&IsDlg=1
```

greetz hechler

Comment: Thanks Hechler for replying, but this is what i am doing in AS3 code. roll._btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick1);
function onClick1(e:MouseEvent):void{
 var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://portal.go.com/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&ListId={46E8A5A2-922C-4B29-907A-F45FCBA3B621}&RootFolder=");
 navigateToURL(req, "_self");
}